# How do i write a rule in prolog called countIt?

Tags: prolog

Write a function in Scheme or rules in Prolog called countlt that takes a list of numbers, L, and another number, N, and returns the count of numbers less than N in the list L.

```
?- countlt([6, 1, 9], 4, X).
X = 1. 

?- countit([50, 27, 13], 1, X).
X = 0.
```

Comment: You could use [include/3](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3) and then length/2.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will solve your problem, if you are looking for a solution without that doesn't use any of the built-in or library predicates:

```
countlt([], _, 0).
countlt([A | B], N, X) :- ((N > A, countlt(B, N, T), X is T + 1); countlt(B, N, X)), !.
```

You could of course expand this into multiple lines but I find this solution more straightforward and with less tampering with cut operators.